# How to shorten function in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on cleaning up my app a little to gain better performance. Rather then having about 5 lines of stuff I want to shorten stuff down. Current in my controller I have;

```
# this pretty much talks with Stripe and grabs our customer token or account id
customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(current_user.stripe_customer_token)

# this grabs the stripeToken card info and creates the credit card
customer.cards.create(:card => params[:stripeToken])
customer.subscriptions.create(:plan => 'subscriber')
customer.save
```

I wanted to shorten stuff up and not sure if this would be a good idea;

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(current_user.stripe_customer_token)
customer.cards.create(:card => params[:stripeToken]) unless customer.cards.present? customer.subscriptions.create(:plan => 'subscriber').save
```

Would that above work? I've got errors, maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: `save` returns `true` or `false` not the saved record. I would argue that the first version is waay more readable

Comment: the second time you got retr**ei**ve instead of retr**ie**ve. But may just be a typo in SO

Comment: Are you trying to make this method shorter, or are you trying to make it faster?

Comment: @dpassage I was thinking making it shorter would be faster :)

Comment: Shorter isn't always faster.  Adding the `unless customer.cards.present?` check will actually make this slower as you're adding iterating over an array to the functionality.

Answer (score 2):

This is technically the same number of lines but a bit more concise in my opinion (untested):

```
Stripe::Customer.retrieve(current_user.stripe_customer_token).tap do |customer|
  customer.cards.create(card: params[:stripeToken])
  customer.subscriptions.create(plan: :subscriber)
end.save
```